# Send parameters between services graphql apollo federation

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server, apollo-federation

I'm looking for some documentation about parameters and resolveReference between services.
Actually, I've got something like that :

Service A typedef

```
type Query {
            orderSummary(storeId: ID!, orderSummaryFilterInput: OrderSummaryFilterInput): OrderSummary
        }
        ...
        extend type OrderSummary @key(fields: "storeId") {
            storeId: String! @external
        }

        input OrderSummaryFilterInput {
            beginDate: Date
            endDate: Date
        }
```

Resolver Service A

```
Query: {
    orderSummary: (_, { storeId, orderSummaryFilterInput } ) => {

        console.log("storeId", storeId); storeId OK
        console.log("orderSummaryFilterInput", orderSummaryFilterInput); // get my filters here

        // send to service B, storeId value is sent, not orderSummaryFilterInput.
        return { __typename: "OrderSummary", storeId, orderSummaryFilterInput }; 
    },
},
```

Typedef Service B

```
        type OrderSummary @key(fields: "storeId") {
            storeId: String!
            count: Int
            amount: Int
        }
```

Resolver Service B

```
OrderSummary: {
                __resolveReference(store, args) {
                    console.log("_", store); // get my storeID here but nothing more
                    console.log("args", args); // no orderSummaryFilter here

                },
            },
```

So, my question is : How can I send parameters (OrderSummaryFilterInput) from service A to service B and above all, I would like to know how can I get parameters in my service B ? I didn't find anything in documentation about this. Thank you very much

Thank you very much

Comment: use context? ....

Comment: Nothing into context variable :/

Comment: console.log("context", context.orderSummaryFilterInput); // undefined

Comment: save sth into context in one resolver, read in another

Comment: Could you provide an example ? I'm really sorry but I'm not sure to understand what I should to. What is "sth" ? Thank you again for your help, I really appreciate because I didn't find anything in Apollo documentation

Comment: context is just an object ... `context.orderSummaryFilterInput = orderSummaryFilterInput;` in `orderSummery` resolver ... `const orderSummaryFilterInput = context.orderSummaryFilterInput;` in `OrderSummary` resolver   ... of course define context as resolver arg

Comment: you can also check `info.variableValues` - from 4th resolver arg

Comment: There are suggestions to send the additional parameters as headers to the subgraph or making the @key a hybrid where the key data contains the parameters and needs parsed on the subgraph side. Is there a better "GraphQL-like" way to do this?